# Meteor return limited values from child array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming

I have a collection with the structure like this:

```
{
  _id: xKdshsdhs7h8
  files: [
      {
         file_name : "1.txt",
         file_path : "/home/user1/"
      },
      {
         file_name : "2.txt",
         file_path : "/home/user2/"
      }
  ]
}
```

And on server im trying to return a cursor which i can use to display all this files on client. Also i want to output a limited amount of files on the page, and let user click 'load more' to show more.
So i can't figure out on how exactly to do this, currently i have:

```
 Meteor.publish("attachments_list_limited", function (count,id) {


        var test =  AttachmentsList.find({_id : id},{limit: count}, {sort: {"files.fileName": -1}});

        return test;

    });
```

So in theory i will get a single object on client, which i can output like this

```
 {{#each attachmentsList.files}}

                        <li class="list-group-item col-xs-3 borderless">

                            <span data-id={{_id}}  class="pull-right">

                                <button class="btn btn-xs btn-delete-attachment" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                                </button>
                            </span>

                            <div  class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body wrapped attachment">{{fileName}}</div>
                            </div>

                        </li>
   {{/each}}
```

But how can i return just a cursor to array elements with limit?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of limiting the publish function to `count` and `id`, pass selector and options instead.

So that it would look like this

```
Meteor.publish("attachments_list_limited", function (selector, options) {
    var test =  AttachmentsList.find(selector, options);
    return test;
});
```

Then on the client side you can set the limit using a Session variable or something like that. And increase it when the button is clicked.

```
Session.setDefault('count', 5);

helper: function () {
    var selector = ...
    var options = ...
    return Attachments.find(selector, options);
}

'click .load': function () {
    Session.set('count', Session.get('count') + 5);
}
```

Comment: Letting the client use an arbitrary selector seems risky.

Answer (score 0):

You have it wrong here:

```
AttachmentsList.find({_id : id},{limit: count}, {sort: {"files.fileName": -1}});
```

It should be like this:

```
AttachmentsList.find({_id : id}, {sort: {"files.fileName": -1}, limit: count});
```

Let me know if it doesn't work and I'll write you a full example.